# How do I change the properties of a child widget by having a method in the root widget?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to do the following.

-i have 'GameScreen' as the root widget.

-When I click a button,I want its color to be changed to green if it is red in color.At the same time,I also want the value of the 'Label' to be incremented by 1.I want to do it by having a method in the GameScreen class.But I am not able to do the latter part.

Please help.I am new to kivy.Below is the kv code.

```
<Button>:
    size_hint:0.33,0.8/3
<GameScreen>:

   Button:
        name:"1"
        text:self.name
        color:1,0,0,1
        pos_hint:{"left":0,"bottom":1}
        on_press:self.color=root.change_color(self.color)
  Button:
        name:"2"
        text:self.name
        color:0,1,0,1
        pos_hint:{"x":0.33,"bottom":1}
        on_press:self.color=root.change_color(self.color)
  Label:
        id:my_score
        size_hint:0.2,0.2
        pos_hint:{"x":0.4,"y":0.8}
        text:"78"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ternary operator in kv language and by using the ';' character you can run multiple statements in one line.

```
<Button>:
    size_hint:0.33,0.8/3

<GameScreen@BoxLayout>:
    Button:
        name:"1"
        text:self.name
        color:(0,1,0,1) if self.pressed else (1,0,0,1)
        pos_hint:{"left":0,"bottom":1}
        pressed: False
        on_press:self.pressed=not self.pressed;my_score.value+=1

    Button:
        name:"2"
        text:self.name
        color:(0,1,0,1) if self.pressed else (1,0,0,1)
        pos_hint:{"x":0.33,"bottom":1}
        pressed: False
        on_press:self.pressed=not self.pressed;my_score.value+=1
    Label:
        id:my_score
        size_hint:0.2,0.2
        pos_hint:{"x":0.4,"y":0.8}
        value: 78
        text:str(self.value)
```

Comment: you can do multiple `on_*` too :P